# R code, CSV file, and ggplot2. Creating reference range, and removing row from plot

Tags: r

I'm very new to R so I apologise if this seems like a very silly question.

So I'm reading in a CSV file and trying to produce a simple line, using ggplot2, which marks the two values I have for someone's haemoglobin levels.

I want to stop it from plotting the first row (which just states the variable names). Is there some code I can insert to stop it from plotting row 1 in my CSV file?
Also, I want to start and end the line at specific values (the reference range for what someone's haemoglobin levels should be), how would I do this? Many thanks in advance. :)

```
require(ggplot2)

# Import the data from a CSV file
data = read.csv("Sample data transposed.csv", header = TRUE)

ggplot(Sample.data.transposed, aes(V6, 0)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(colour = "red", size = 4) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.05) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_size_area() + 
  xlab("Haemoglobin") +
  ylab("") +
  ggtitle("Haemoglobin values")


          V1            V2                 V3   V4            V5          V6
1       Date Reticulocytes Imm Retic Fraction  RBC Nucleated RBC Haemoglobin
2 05/10/2012            61               <NA> 4.41          <NA>        14.4
3 21/11/2012            69               11.1 4.52             0        14.3
```

Comment: Can you show us the head of your data set ? head(data)

Comment: @Chargaff I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I can't upload a picture, but here is a link to it http://tinypic.com/r/apczya/5

Comment: Chargaff is asking, if your data frame object is `data`, please type `dput(head(data))` into the console and post the output for us.

Answer (score 2):

The straight answer is to take out the first row with something like:

```
ggplot(data[-1,],...)
```

However, I don't think you'll be able to plot with that. Here's why.

From your link of the data structure, there are two lines worth of header in your CSV. Your first line is generic column names `V1`, `V2`, etc. Your second line is the actual column headers. This likely is changing the datatype of your columns to `factor` or `character` instead of the `numeric` it needs to be to plot.

I'd use a `file` object to read the first line, and then use the second line as the header data for your data frame.

```
ff <- file("Sample data transposed.csv", "r")
readLines(ff, n = 1)
data <- read.csv(ff, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

For changing limits in `ggplot2`, look at `xlim`, `ylim`, `scale_x_continuous`, and `coord_cartesian`.